# Adding char to linked list

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

I am trying to write an abstract data type to represent sets of integer items using linked lists.
My program works fine for this. I want to use user input sentence and store this in decimal value for input to the linked-list set.
My program crashes when I enter more than 10 chars in this sentence and I'm not sure why. Below is the long code with the fgets input highlighted with *** at the bottom.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <strings.h>

struct linkedListElement{
int data;
struct linkedListElement * next;
                    };

struct linkedListSet {


struct linkedListElement * header;
struct linkedListElement * current;
struct linkedListElement * temp;
int size;
                };

struct linkedListSet * createdSet (){

struct linkedListSet * newSet = malloc(sizeof(struct linkedListSet));

newSet->header = malloc(sizeof(struct linkedListElement));
    newSet->current = malloc(sizeof(struct linkedListElement));
    newSet->temp = malloc(sizeof(struct linkedListElement));
newSet->size = 0;
return newSet;
}

int addItem (struct linkedListSet * setPtr, int info){

    if(linkedList_lookup(setPtr, info)){return 0;}
        struct linkedListElement * newElementPtr = malloc(sizeof(struct      linkedListElement));

newElementPtr->data = info;

if(setPtr->header->data == 0){
    setPtr->header = newElementPtr;
    }//if first element set as header

if(setPtr->current->data != 0){ //if it is not first element last element points to       new element 
    setPtr->current->next = newElementPtr;
                                }

setPtr->current = newElementPtr; 
setPtr->size++;

return 1;

};

int linkedList_remove(struct linkedListSet * setPtr, int item){
if(!linkedList_lookup(setPtr, item)){return 0;};

linkedList_lookup(setPtr, item);

setPtr->temp->next = setPtr->current->next;
setPtr->size--;

return 1;

};



int linkedList_lookup(struct linkedListSet * setToBeSearched, int numToFind){

struct linkedListElement * i;
i= setToBeSearched->header;
int found = 0;
int count = 0;
setToBeSearched->temp = setToBeSearched->header;

for(count = 0, i= setToBeSearched->header; i->next !=NULL,count<setToBeSearched-    >size; i = i->next, count++){

    if(i->data == numToFind){ found = 1; setToBeSearched->current =     i;}//current points to : found matching element
    else if(found != 1){ setToBeSearched->temp = i;}// temp points to : element     before found matching element 
}
if(found){return 1;}
return 0;
};




void printMyList(struct linkedListSet * setToBePrinted){

struct linkedListElement * i;
int count = 0;
for (count = 0, i = setToBePrinted->header; count<setToBePrinted->size; i = i-  >next, count++){
    printf(" %d", i->data);

};
printf("\n");

};


int main(){
//create set
struct linkedListSet * firstSet = createdSet();
struct linkedListSet * secondSet = createdSet();
struct linkedListSet * comboSet = createdSet();



addItem(firstSet, 300);
addItem(firstSet, 200);
addItem(firstSet, 100);
addItem(firstSet, 5);
addItem(firstSet, 37);
addItem(firstSet, 299);
addItem(firstSet, 201);
addItem(firstSet, 101);
addItem(firstSet, 51);
addItem(firstSet, 371);
addItem(firstSet, 301);
addItem(firstSet, 202);
addItem(firstSet, 102);
addItem(firstSet, 52);
addItem(firstSet, 377);
addItem(firstSet, 305);
addItem(firstSet, 205);
addItem(firstSet, 150);
addItem(firstSet, 55);
addItem(firstSet, 375);
addItem(firstSet, 259);
addItem(firstSet, 251);
addItem(firstSet, 151);
addItem(firstSet, 551);
addItem(firstSet, 571);
addItem(firstSet, 3501);
addItem(firstSet, 2052);
addItem(firstSet, 1052);
addItem(firstSet, 525);
addItem(firstSet, 3757);

addItem(secondSet, 340);
addItem(secondSet, 200);
addItem(secondSet, 120);
addItem(secondSet, 52);
addItem(secondSet, 3799);
addItem(secondSet, 341);
addItem(secondSet, 201);
addItem(secondSet, 121);
addItem(secondSet, 521);
addItem(secondSet, 3792);
addItem(secondSet, 342);
addItem(secondSet, 202);
addItem(secondSet, 122);
addItem(secondSet, 53);
addItem(secondSet, 3739);
addItem(secondSet, 3440);
addItem(secondSet, 2040);
addItem(secondSet, 1240);
addItem(secondSet, 524);
addItem(secondSet, 37499);
addItem(secondSet, 3441);
addItem(secondSet, 2041);
addItem(secondSet, 1241);
addItem(secondSet, 5241);
addItem(secondSet, 37492);
addItem(secondSet, 3442);
addItem(secondSet, 2042);
addItem(secondSet, 1242);
addItem(secondSet, 534);
addItem(secondSet, 37439);

printMyList(firstSet);

if(linkedList_lookup(firstSet, 100)){
    printf(" \nfound number in list");
    };


printf("\ncurrent data is now set to : %d  and temp to : %d\n",firstSet->current->data, firstSet->temp-> data);

linkedList_remove(firstSet, 100);

printMyList(firstSet);

//**********************************************************************
struct linkedListSet * charSet = createdSet();
char strBuff1[60];

printf(" Please enter sentence: ");
fgets(strBuff1, 60, stdin);

int i = 0;

for ( int i = 0 ; strBuff1[i] != 0; i++){
    printf(" %c ", strBuff1[i]);
    addItem(charSet, strBuff1[i]);
}
//***********************************************************************
return (0);


}
```

Comment: I am new to using fgets and feel there must be a better way to implement the code highlighted at the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
i->next !=NULL,count<setToBeSearched->size
```

should be

```
i->next !=NULL && count<setToBeSearched->size
```

should it not?

You are not setting the newElementPtr->next pointer in addItem.

There are a few other problems too

struct linkedListSet should contain pointers to the struct linkedListElement you have created. Copying data from these structures into duplicated linkedListElement in the struct linkedListSet is unreliable and unnecessary.

Also, typedefs for your structs would make the code easier to read.

Comment: wow thank you so much for this help. The && has stopped the program from crashing and am working on the second change now. Can't thank you enough.

Comment: I have to say the program still crashed for me after I fixed that, so don't get your hopes up too much :) Have a good look at that linkListSet struct, it is definitely a weak link. You should not need that temp field, and linked lists should be terminated with a null next pointer anyway, so size isn't strictly needed.

Comment: Ok thanks again - I am working through these changes. I will add a NULL pointer to addItem new elements and also initialise first element(header) to NULL point initially. I am using the temp pointer for the _remove function so that previous element points to element that removed element pointed to.

Comment: I will try get rid of size and change for loop conditions to just != NULL